# Creating and linking a .o file with Haskell foreign function export and no main function in C

Tags: c, haskell, linker, ghc, ffi

I am familiar with the approach of calling a Haskell function from C as defined here:

https://wiki.haskell.org/Calling_Haskell_from_C

However, instead of creating an executable, what I want to do is create a `.o` that will be later linked with other `.o` files. My scenario is something like this:

**Safe.hs**

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module Safe where

import Foreign.C.Types

fibonacci :: Int -> Int
fibonacci n = fibs !! n
    where fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)

fibonacci_hs :: CInt -> CInt
fibonacci_hs = fromIntegral . fibonacci . fromIntegral

foreign export ccall fibonacci_hs :: CInt -> CInt
```

But the C file is different, doesn't have a `main` function

**test.c**

```
#include <HsFFI.h>
#ifdef __GLASGOW_HASKELL__
#include "Safe_stub.h"
#endif

int foo()
{
    int i;
    // some dummy values for argc and argv
    hs_init(&argc, &argv);

    i = fibonacci_hs(42);

    hs_exit();
    return i;
}
```

Now to link them together into a .o file I tried something like this:

```
ghc -fPIE -c -O Safe.hs
```

emits a `Safe_stub.h`, `Safe.o` and `Safe.hi` files.

Next, I compile the `test.c` file into an object file

```
ghc --make -fPIE -no-hs-main -optc-O -c test.c -o test.o
```

gives me the `test.o` object file that I am looking for.

Now, I attempt to link the two object files produced and I use ghc's linker (that internally uses gcc):

```
ghc -no-hs-main -optc-nostartfiles -optc-static-pie test.o Safe.o -o result.o
```

Here is what I get

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:function _start: error: undefined reference to 'main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

So, it seems somewhere the object files have a reference to `main`. Is it a matter of passing some flags? Or what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

A suggestion was made to use plain `ld -r` to link the object files. The problem with that approach is that if vanilla `ld` is used, it will not link in the Haskell runtime needed to actually make the object file useful and callable by another C program as a library.

If it wasn't clear from my post, I want to create a .o file that can be used as a C library that calls into the Haskell code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was my solution to the problem after a lot of playing with various flags

```
ghc -c -O Safe.hs
ghc -c -no-hs-main -optc-O test.c
```

I don't know what the `--make` flag was adding. Now imagine you distributed the `Safe.o` and `test.o` produced from the above. To compile it with a C function that actually has a `main` method like:

**testfoo.c**

```
extern int foo();

int main(){
        int k = foo();
        return k;
}
```

you would do:

```
ghc -no-hs-main testfoo.c test.o Safe.o
```

The produced executable would have the Haskell runtime linked in of course.

Answer (score 1):

Normally a linker is used to combine multiple object files into a single executable, which naturally must have a `main` as its entry point. Apparently it is possible to combine multiple object files into a single object file, with `ld -r`. Does GHC have a flag to behave this way? Maybe, but I couldn't immediately find it.

But if you're just going to use GHC to invoke the linker, why not invoke the linker yourself?

```
ld -r test.o Safe.o -o result.o
```